# Alternative way to recognize that a real symmetric quadratic form is positive

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry, quadratic-forms

A *real* symmetric quadratic form $g(x)=\varSigma_{1\leq i,j \leq n}\,g_{ij} x^i x^j$ is *positive* *(definite)* if $g(x)>0$  for every $\mathbb{R}^n\ni x=(x^1,...,x^n)\neq 0$. It is well known that a real symmetric quadratic form is positive iff all eingenvalues of the symmetric matrix $M=(g_{ij})$ are positive. This can be verified applying Descartes' rule of alternating signs to the characteristic polynomial, as it has no complex roots.

**Question**:   is there a considerably simpler way to recognize that $g(x)$  is positive without needing to find the characteristic polynomial of the associated matrix $(g_{ij})$?

This would be useful, for instance, to recognize that a family of maps $g_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^n\supset U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defines locally a Riemannian metric $\langle v,w\rangle_y=\varSigma_{1\leq i,j \leq n}\,g_{ij}(y) v^i w^j$ on a manifold.

Comment: There is [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion).

Comment: @Siméon: actually a simpler way, but I wonder if a more direct criterion can be given.

Comment: I don't know, but in your example of a family of (hopefully) metrics $g_{ij}$ parametrized by an open subset $U$ you might try something like 1) identify a suitable reference point within that family, 2) show that in a suitable neighborhood of the reference point the eigenvalues remain real and positive. In other words view the "metric" at other points as perturbed versions of the reference metric. You need a tool in estimating how the (smallest) eigenvalue(s) changes when you move around. Should be known, but I'm afraid I cannot point you at a source.

Comment: @Jyrki: precisely, the question was how to build "new" Riemannian metrics, that are not perturbations of known ones.